# Problema con DOUBLE en el RESPONSE <?> PHP

Tags: php, json, array, double, response

Buen dia,

Estoy creando un servicio web que hace una consulta a mi base y me regresa un arreglo con varios elementos. el problema que tengo es que cuando lo corro en el LOCAL los DOUBLE me los imprime correcto, cuando lo subo al SERVIDOR, los DOUBLE me imprime decimales de mas, ya revise la configuración de mi servidor y lo coloque en versión PHP 7.3,  Si lo imprimo como STRING si me respeta los 2 decimales, en mi base de datos, esta configurado DOUBLE (6,2 ).

Les comparto mi codigo y el response.
Los campos son DISCOUNTFROM y DISCOUNTTO

```
    $mysql = "SELECT DISTINCT t1.`upc`, t2.`nameProduct1` AS productName, t1.`twoXOne`, t1.`threeXtwo`, t1.`discount`, t1.`discountFrom` , ";
    $mysql .= "t1.`discountTo`  , t1.`other`, t1.`otherDescription`";
    $mysql .= "FROM `promotions` AS t1 LEFT JOIN `product` AS t2 ON t1.`upc` = t2.`upc` WHERE t1.`codeCostumer` = ? AND t1.`codeStore` = ?";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($mysql);
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $idCostumer, $codeStore);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $promotion[] = $row;
        }

        for ($r = 0; $r < count($promotion); $r ++) {
            $promotion[$r]['twoXOne'] = boolval($promotion[$r]['twoXOne']);
            $promotion[$r]['threeXtwo'] = boolval($promotion[$r]['threeXtwo']);
            $promotion[$r]['discount'] = boolval($promotion[$r]['discount']);
            $promotion[$r]['discountFrom'] = doubleval($promotion[$r]['discountFrom']);
            $promotion[$r]['discountTo'] = doubleval($promotion[$r]['discountTo']);
            $promotion[$r]['other'] = boolval($promotion[$r]['other']);
        }
        echo json_encode($promotion);
```

El response que me arroja es el siguente

*******RESPONSE******

```
    {
    "upc": "8975463124851",
    "productName": "Pasta caracol",
    "twoXOne": false,
    "threeXtwo": false,
    "discount": true,
    "discountFrom": 99.9899999999999948840923025272786617279052734375,
    "discountTo": 89.9899999999999948840923025272786617279052734375,
    "other": false,
    "otherDescription": ""
  }
```

Agradezco su tiempo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que estás planteando puede ocurrir debido a un bug con respecto a `json_encode` según el cual la función utilizaba `EG(precision)`.

Dicho bug fue reportado en el año 2015. [Aquí se puede ver el seguimiento](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/precise_float_value) y una solución propuesta. Según esa página la propuesta fue aceptada y la implementaron en la versión `7.1` de PHP:

> Implementation
>
> Merged into php-src for PHP 7.1:
>   https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/75b86a2

El asunto ha sido tratado con amplitud en [Stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42981409/5587982), sobre todo [en esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43056278/5587982), donde se explica con mayor detalle lo que ocurre (traducción de la explicación):

> Actualmente `json_encode()` usa `EG(precisión)` que se establece en
>   14. Eso significa que se usan 14 dígitos como máximo para mostrar (imprimir) el número. IEEE754 double admite una mayor precisión y
>   `serialize()` / `var_export()` usa `PG(serialize_precision)` que se
>   establece en 17 por defecto para ser más preciso. Como `json_encode()`
>   usa `EG(precisión)`, `json_encode()` elimina los dígitos más bajos de
>   las partes de fracción y destruye el valor original incluso si el
>   flotante de PHP podría contener un valor flotante más preciso.

Una solución **temporal** podría ser esta:

```
/*Convendría retirar este código cuando tengas una versión con el bug corregido*/
if (version_compare(phpversion(), '7.1', '>=')) {
    ini_set( 'precision', 17 );
    ini_set( 'serialize_precision', -1 );
}
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que esto cambia la configutación en al archivo `php.ini`.

Comment: Gracias!! me funcion perfecto, ire revisando la decoumentacion de PHP, para revisar cuando resuelva enste bug!.